# add one day of start day for checkout pikaday datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, css

For the checkout, I want to add 1 day of check-in. for example, today is 8 November 2017, then I clicked check on 10 November 2017 for example, then it should be 11 November 2017 on checkout.

html code :

```
<input name="arrival_guest" type="text"  class="form-control" id="start">
<input name="departure_guest" type="text"  class="form-control" id="end">
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/wildanisa72/6zfhz9sh/1/) my code I put in fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```js
var picker = new Pikaday({
    field: document.getElementById('start'),
    firstDay: 1,
        minDate: new Date(currentDate.getTime() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
        maxDate: new Date(2090, 12, 31),
        yearRange: [2000,2090],
    onSelect: function() {
        var selectedDate = new Date(this.getDate());
        var checkOutDate = new Date(selectedDate.getFullYear(), selectedDate.getMonth(), selectedDate.getDate()+1);
        picker2.setMinDate(checkOutDate);
    }, 
    onClose : function() {
       var selectedDate = this.getDate();
       var checkOutDate = new Date(selectedDate.getFullYear(), selectedDate.getMonth(), selectedDate.getDate()+1 );
       picker2.setDate(checkOutDate);
    }
});
var picker2 = new Pikaday({
    field: document.getElementById('end'),
    onClose : function() {
       var selectedDate = this.getDate();
       var checkInDate = new Date(selectedDate.getFullYear(), selectedDate.getMonth(), selectedDate.getDate()-1 );
       picker.setDate(checkInDate);
    }
});
```

Comment: the previous date for checkout must be disabled (can't click)

Comment: just disabled the date before for checkout @sunwoo

Comment: hi @sunwoo thx but when I clicked on the checkout automatically the checkin date change, it shouldn't be change when the first I choose date on check in

Comment: please help me @sunwoo I think you are the one who will save my life hehe

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want to do, but I think it's going to delete the OnClose function.

Answer (score 0):

try like this in onchange event of first datepicker

```
$('.start').change(function() {
var date2 = $('.start').datepicker('getDate', '+1d'); 
 date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1); 
$('.end').datepicker('setDate', date2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet to increment date. You place it on `change` event of start input.

```js
var startValue  = document.getElementById('start').value;

var dateObj = new Date(startValue);

dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate() + 1);

var endDate = dateObj.getFullYear() +"-"+ dateObj.getMonth() +"-"+ dateObj.getDate();

document.getElementById('end').value = endDate;
```

```html
<input name="arrival_guest" type="text"  class="form-control" id="start" value="2017-11-19">
<input name="departure_guest" type="text"  class="form-control" id="end">
```

**UPDATE:** From my understanding (since you weren't very clear about your aimed result), you want to set minimum date of `departure_guest` from the value selected at `arrival_guest`. I have prepared [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dani0332/819kah65/) **it works fine**

Comment: @Wilda Check the updated answer, it has a link of working fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

try like this in your code

```
picker2.setMinDate(this.getDate());
    var a = convert(this.getDate());
    document.getElementById('end').value = a;
```

add below function

```
function convert(str) {
var date = new Date(str);
    var d = date.getDate()+1;
 var m = date.getMonth();
 var y = date.getFullYear();
 var edate= new Date(y, m, d+1);
return [y,m,d].join("-");
}
```